# Long run equilibrium price under perfect competition

Tags: microeconomics, competition, competitive-equilibrium, perfect-competition

I have a problem related to Ricardian rent.

I have one firm, let's call it X firm, and all of the other firms in the market. All firms have to pay some transportation costs due to their land except for X firm.

I also know that their cost functions are first degree polynomials, meaning that their marginal cost and average cost is equal to a constant number(Different than each other of course as X firm doesn't have to pay any transportation costs.)

How can I obtain the equilibrium price using only this data? I couldn't evaluate the single firm's affect on the price, does it have any influence over the price?

Comment: Based on your studies of equilibrium, do you have any notions that could be applied here, and have you tried any of them? (This seems like a fairly straightforward exercise.)

Comment: In general, to find equilibrium, I solve it by equalizing demand function to the supply function. In the perfectly competitive markets, only knowing the costs functions is enough to determine the market price. We add supply curves of the firms horizontally to obtain equilibrium. However, the fact that firms have constant and different cost functions got me confused. Cost function for X is 150q, for the rest of the firms is 155q. AC=MC=Supply curve for firm X is 150, and fot  rest of the firms it is 155. Would be very glad if you could give further tips.

Comment: From the cost functions, you should be able to tell for any price $p$ what quantity each company is willing to supply. (Are there capacity constraints?) It could be that a company is indifferent between supplying several different output levels; this happens when pricing is at cost. The question is, is there a price level at which the supply could equal demand?

Comment: If for individual firms the marginal and average costs are equal to each other and constant, then the lowest cost firm can take the whole market, charging marginally less than the marginal cost of the second-lowest-cost firm.   The difference between this an the lowest-cost firm's cost is the rent

Comment: @Henry So, at equilibrium, would market price be the same as the second-lowest-cost firm's cost?

Comment: @Giskard Sorry to disturb again, but I am stuck on this problem for quite a long time. In competitive markets firms produce at MC=MR. And in this question MC=AC. So, no firm makes profit. However, there should exist only one price and as  marginal costs of firms are different and constant, mar.price and marginal cost of A, and ma.price and marginal cost of rest of the firms can never intersect at the same time. Meaning that price can only be equal to one of the marginal costs. What happens to other? Do you think I am missing something here? Btw there exists a production limit as you mentioned.

Comment: @madetolast At this point I recommend contacting your TA, I am sure she will be delighted to talk it over with you. The basic concepts are there.